# Renaming and moving wildcard files with Bash

Tags: linux, bash, rename, mv, eyed3

I'm trying to do the following with this bash script but i've come unstuck..

**1) Find every file with the extension .mp3 in the /usr/incoming/ directory**

**2) Use eyeD3 to strip all of the existing ID3 tags**

**3) Use eyeD3 to write a title tag "NEW NAME" back to the file**

**4) Use mv to rename every file with the extension .mp3 to latest.mp3 and then force move it (so it will overwrite any other file with the same name) to the usr/complete directory.**

It's all working apart from the last bit (No.4).

I know i'm doing something wrong with the mv command but I'm not sure what.

Here's the code :

```
 find /usr/incoming/ -name '*.mp3' \
   -exec eyeD3 --remove-all -t 'NEW NAME' '{}' \; \
   -exec mv -f '*.mp3' latest.mp3 /usr/complete \;
```

Can anybody show me the error of my ways? ;)

Comment: Do you want to write all the files to `latest.mp3` or do something like move `file.mp3` to `file.latest.mp3`?

Comment: When you say `-exec mv -f '*.mp3'`, that passes THE LITERAL STRING `*.mp3` to `mv`, not a list of filenames that matched.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change the `*.mp3` in your later command to `{}` to pass in an explicit name of the file you just tagged. `mv` will refuse to rename multiple files to the same name in a single invocation -- when passed more than two arguments, it requires the last to be a directory -- and anyhow, anything given as an argument to find's `-exec` is passed as a literal argument, not through a shell, so globs aren't expanded, redirections aren't processed, etc. except for find's own special strings such as `{}`.

```
find /usr/incoming/ -name '*.mp3' \
   -exec eyeD3 --remove-all -t 'NEW NAME' {} ';' \
   -exec mv -f {} /usr/complete/latest.mp3 ';'
```

Comment: Probably worth putting an `echo` in front of the `mv`, since I can't image why the intent would be to rename every file `latest.mp3`, and in doing so blow away all but the last to be renamed.

Comment: Thanks Charles, that works perfectly!

@BroSlow - there is a valid reason for doing it this way. Basically it's for importing the latest version of a radio show. The software being used for scheduling won't dynamically load new files into a preassigned playlist - so this is a hack to keep replacing the "latest.mp3" with a new file so that the automation system is tricked into thinking that it's playing the same file when it is fact going to be playing a different one every week ;)